# string in double quotes after a map operation in Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use Kafka streams DSL and map to convert a `KStream<String, JsonNode>` to `KStream<String, String>`.

In `ValueMapper` function, I simple return `new ValueMapper("key", "some constant string")`, but where the value is sent back to Kafka use `KStream.to("some topic")`, I got the result is being added double quotes.

my code is like this:

```
KStream<String, JsonNode> views = builder.stream("fromTopic");
views.map(new ValueKMapper()).to("toTopic");
```

and `ValueMapper` simply implements `KeyValueMapper` and the code of `apply()` is:

```
public KeyValue<String, String> apply(String key, JsonNode value) 
{
    return new KeyValue<String,String>("a", "hello");
}
```

and then when I consume the `toTopic`, I got the `""hello""`, with quotes added.

Maybe it's a bug of Kafka streams?

Comment: Can you show all the code as a [mcve]?

Comment: `ValueMapper` is an interface... You cannot call `new` on this. Can you share the code snippet?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I just return a new KeyValue<String,String>.

Comment: I add the code in the question, thanks all.

Comment: How do you consumer the output topic?

Comment: I use both java program and console-consumer  script, the result is the same. For java program, just set the `@KafkaListener(topics =  "toTopic")`  and call ConsumerRecord.value().  For shell, `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server xx:9092 --topic toTopic`. I think the test method is nothing wrong.

Comment: Is this behavior observed with both keys and values?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I use the `map` for two types. For one case, I use map to convert from KStream<String, String> to KStream<String, String>, the result is OK,  without quotes add.  For another case, I use map to convert from KStream<String, JsonNode> to KStream<String, String> the result value is quotes added. Both the apply() for KeyValueMapper directly return a new KeyValue<String, String>("constant string","constant string").

Comment: Not sure atm. What `Serde` do you use? Maybe the Serde is incorrect and messes it up? Try `to("outputTopc", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String());`

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax It's OK for us, I thought the KStream type is KStream<String,String>, so the Serde is auto set to String Serde...

Comment: No. Java does not allow this. It's call "type erasure" -- at runtime, the generic type information is not available any longer, and thus it's not possible to pick a Serde based on generic types automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the method `apply()` you've provided in your question

```
public KeyValue<String, String> apply(String key, JsonNode value) 
{
    return new KeyValue<String,String>("a", "hello");
}
```

is not passing hardcoded key and value to `KeyValue`'s constructor. My guess is that the problem has something to do with `JsonNode`. Maybe, the actual implementation of your method uses `value.get(key)` i.e.

```
public KeyValue<String, String> apply(String key, JsonNode value) 
{
    return new KeyValue<String,String>(key, value.get(key));
}
```

However, `value.get(key)` will return a `TextNode` and the `toString()` method will return a string representation of `TextNode` including quotes. In order to parse `JsonNode` properly, you need to use `textValue()` method so your method will become

```
public KeyValue<String, String> apply(String key, JsonNode value) 
{
    return new KeyValue<String,String>(key, value.get(key).textValue());
}
```

**Example:** 
Assuming you have a key `a` and a value `hello`,

```
json.get("a").toString())
```

will return `"hello"` while

```
json.get("a").textValue();
```

will return `hello`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I'm sorry in order to avoid some possible reasons, I really new a `KeyValue` with constant string, it's none of the business with `JsonNode` I think.

Comment: I resolved the problem by add Serde.String()  to  the KStream.to("toTopic", Serde.String(), Serde.String()).

Answer (score 0):

It could happen that you are using Json serde as default. Try adding string serde when writing to sink:

```
.to("toTopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
```